# VB.Net Pass a List (of) to a WriteOnly Property sub

Tags: vb.net, list

Net v4.6 - VS2015

Take the following code:

I have a class (KeywordClass) with some properties, a module with a declaration of

```
 Friend _ImportKeywords As New List(Of String)
```

and a Write only property on the class of:

```
 Public WriteOnly Property ImportKeywords() As List(Of String)
 Set(ByVal value As List(Of String))
        _ImportKeywords = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I am trying to pass a list to the property from outside of the class.

```
 Dim Kwords As New List(Of String)
 Kwords.add("testing")
 Kwords.add("hello")
 Kwords.add("goodbye")


  Using MyClass As New KeywordClass
  MyClass.ImportKeywords(Kwords)
  End Using
```

but Im getting the error:
Too many arguments to 'Public WriteOnly Property ImportKeywords As List(Of String)'

I've done a fair bit of searching and all the results that have been solutions seem to point to just passing the list - which is what I have done above. Nothing else seems to work and Im probably missing the obvious. IIf someone can help me, I'd be very appreciative. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: It is a property, not a method, so you'll surely favor MyClass.ImportKeywords = Kwords.  Right now the compiler loses its marbles because it thinks you are trying to use an indexed property.

Comment: I've lost the plot!!! How did I miss that. DOH ! Thanks Hans. Its been a long long week and I am just glad its Friday. Thanks again pal.